# barcode_scan not running on Flutter Web app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a fully functional app. I use barcode_scan in the app, but when called on the web app, it does not launch. Any help?

Comment: Try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/qr_bar_code_scanner_dialog/example

Answer (score 1):

`barcode_scan` doesn't claim support for flutter web as you can see on the [package site](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan). As can be seen in the description, this package simply provides a wrapper for existing barcode scanning packages for both iOS and android.